# how to call a service inside a node?

Tags: navigation, odometry, service, call-service, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with summitXL. After reaching the target point I would like to set the odometry by calling the ros service "/summit_a/set_odometry". How can I call the service inside the node. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201617/how-to-call-a-service-inside-a-node?/) by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2015-01-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

Please check here:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

Probably you are looking for: Writing a Simple Service and Client (C++)

---

Originally posted by [IliaBaranov](https://answers.ros.org/users/11601/iliabaranov/) with karma: 101 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2015-01-23**:
thanks for the ans. but all I need is to call a predefined service inside my node.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-23**:
Which is exactly what the *service client* tutorial teaches you.

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2015-01-23**:
but I have to call the service in the callback function where it has no nodehandle object.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-12**:
You should store the NodeHandle somewhere that can be accessed inside the callback so you can use it.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-08-05**:
Instead of writing all these, a simple answer would be convenient for everyone. Besides, even in that tutorial, it's not clear. There is `add_two_ints` variable, said to be handle, but should it have the same name when it's a function or a variable, it's vague.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can call a ros service inside a node like:

```
import rosservice
rosservice.call_service("YOUR_SERVICE_NAME",[Arguments])
```

---

Originally posted by [mustafadurmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/46441/mustafadurmus/) with karma: 31 on 2019-10-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3